# CUDA installation on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, cuda

Cuda installation broke when I installed python-pyopencl from apt repository. Even as I have removed the OpenCL and nvidia-current that was installed as dependency and installed drivers from nvidia. I get error when I try to run deviceQuery.

The machine in question is a headless server, with multiple cards. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a complete reinstall of CUDA.  Don't use the repositories.

Download the appropriate CUDA 6 Ubuntu 12.04 linux installer (i.e. runfile) from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda)

and run it.

Use the runfile installation method as described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile).

Comment: I did a 'apt-get remove --purge' before using the 'runfile'. That did the trick.